# java incorrect date format

Tags: java, parsing, date

I wrote the following code to parse a simple date like "09-MAR-17":

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    Date start = null;
    Date end = null;
    try {
        start = df.parse(data.get(i)[Columns.PACKAGESTART.ordinal()]);
        end = df.parse(data.get(i)[Columns.PACKAGEEND.ordinal()]);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However this throws the following exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "07-MAR-17"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
```

However i dont know why. Is "dd-MMM-yy" an incorrect format?

EDIT: running this in netbeans gives me an exception, running the exact same code in eclipse seems to work.

Comment: IIRC `MMM` will expect `Mar` not `MAR`.

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me

Comment: I've just tested your code, and it work's fine: http://ideone.com/nA1x7z So `SimpleDateFormat` is case-insensitive.

Comment: @Crozin Why were you testing with 1997 as year?

Comment: @peter.petrov It's just a random year, there's no story behind 1997. :) EDIT: Ops... I just realized that date format expected two-digit year. I've fixed my Ideone snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented with this a bit and found that the parsing is locale-dependent. For instance, "07-MAY-17" will work with an English locale but not a Swedish one (where the month of May is named "maj"). I would suspect something similar is happening for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need following extension to your code in order to parse the string "MAR" (english!):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.US);
```

As @SmallHacker has supposed it is a localization problem in parsing.